# Convert int64 column to date format

Tags: python, dataframe, date

I have a column with years, only years, the column format is int64.
How I convert this column to data format?
I have tried datetime, astype, pd.to_datetime, but when I used this the format included days, months, hours....

Thank you.

I have tried datetime, as type.

Comment: What is your actual input and expected output ?

Comment: A year is not a date.  As an example, what conversion would you expect to see for the year 1985?

Comment: Hello friend! It looks like you're seeking help with a specific problem. I suggest referring to the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for guidelines on asking clear and defined questions. Providing better examples, explaining your attempted solutions, and clearly stating your expected outcome will help others to provide you better answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use to_datetime function in pandas and in that case you have to specify your format, since only the year is not the standard one:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format="%Y")
```